What are the step-by-step process and potential consequences of changing name of a Scopus-Indexed Journal?
I work in a central bank in Asia region. My institution regularly publishes a journal, and it is a Scopus-indexed journal. In order to improve the journal's visibility, we are exploring the idea of changing the name (rebranding) of our journal. What steps do we need for it, what are the potential consequences on the current index or performance (CiteScore, Impact Factor, etc) of our journal?

Maybe if you say what investigations you have done yourself, or what happened when you looked on the Scopus website or contacted Scopus, then you might get some replies here. But this is quite an unusual thing to do and perhaps nobody here has any experience of it.
